# Unity Editor UI Error

Tags: unity3d, ui

*Использую версию юнити 2022.3.10f.
Десктоп (пк).
Видеокарта: Geforce GTX 1660 TI ROG STRIX GAMING 6 gb.
Процессор: intel core i9 12700 kf.
32 gb RAM*

Во время использовании юнити столкнулся с проблемой, что **UI эдитора становится черным**, когда я пытаюсь его расширить или изменить, когда открываю аниматора. При этом у меня стоит последний драйвер 546.01 Studio.
На старом компьютере все было хорошо, однако на новом столкнулся с такой проблемой, которую никак не могу решить. Переустановка не помогает.

(скриншоты приложил)
Прошу помощи!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помогло добавление вот этого к ярлыку

```
-force-d3d12
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]